# Publicar uma mesma pergunta no SOpt e SOen

Tags: debate

Gostaria de saber dos outros membros se é legal (do ponto de vista pessoal (agradável/desagradável, bom/ruim)) publicar um mesma pergunta no `SOpt` e no `SOen` (no seu respectivo idioma) visando que ela possa atingir um publico maior?

Comment: Do meu ponto de vista é legal sim, pois se é uma duvida que pode ser útil  a mais usuários. Eu geralmente faço isto.

Comment: Essa pergunta é diferente [desta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/735/215), [desta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125/215), [desta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1993/215) ou [desta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1072/215)? Se o que você quer é saber se pode, a resposta é **sim**. Agora, se o que você quer é a opinião da comunidade sobre o assunto, por favor use a tag `debate` em vez de `suporte`.

Comment: Gostaria da opinião, pois esta situação a meu ver parece com a da criança que pede algo a mãe e não consegue e depois pede pro pai como se nada tive-se acontecido.

Comment: Eu acho que o importante é contribuir com a comunidade, eu só descobri o StackOverflow porque alguém que teve uma dúvida semelhante a minha usou a comunidade para pedir esclarecimentos. Se a pergunta é boa e **ainda não** foi feita (tanto aqui quanto no SOen), qual o problema em fazê-la?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Não vejo mal nenhum, muito pelo contrário: se eu soubesse falar russo e japonês, publicaria no SOru e SOja também. Desde que a pergunta estivesse no escopo dos mesmos, é claro (nem todo conteúdo aceito no SOpt seria aceito no SOen, embora alguns fossem bem vindos em outros sites da rede, como o programmers.SE).

- Se eu quero uma resposta, expor a pergunta pro maior número possível de pessoas aumenta minhas chances de obtê-la.
- Se outras pessoas têm a mesma dúvida que eu, ter o par pergunta/resposta em mais de um idioma aumenta o **alcance** daquela informação (pois quem fala um idioma e não o outro não irá se beneficiar daquele conhecimento se o mesmo só estiver disponível naquele que ele não entende).

Em outras palavras, eu só vejo benefícios, nenhum ponto negativo. E se você recebe uma boa resposta em um mas não em outro, você também pode traduzir a resposta aceita no outro site (citando a fonte, é claro) de modo a trazer aquele conhecimento para a outra comunidade.